# Element 'html_block' was not found in OrderedDict

Tags: python, django, markdown

When using the following code:

```
 MARKDOWN_KWARGS = {
'extensions': [
    'footnotes',
    'attr_list',
    'headerid',
    'extra',
    'codehilite',
],

'safe_mode': 'escape',
```

I receive the following error:

```
 Django Version:    1.6.11
 Exception Type:    ValueError
 Exception Value:   
 Element 'html_block' was not found in OrderedDict
 Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markdown/odict.py in index, line 149
 Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python
 Python Version:    2.7.9
```

Why? And what can I do to fix it?

SOLVED by delete 'safe_mode': 'escape',

Comment: what were you trying to do with your dict, a tleast post the line where you process the dict!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You have discovered a bug in Python-Markdown. Specifically, there is an incompatibility between setting `safe_mode` to "escape" and using the "extra" extension. Under the hood, when `safe_mode` is set to "escape" the parser simply does not insert the preprocessor which finds all of the HTML blocks (which is named 'html_block'). Later, any HTML is then escaped as it is not specifically marked as known safe HTML. However, the "extra" extension attempts to modify the behavior of the 'html_block' preprocessor (to enable the "markdown=1" behavior), and because you are in `safe_mode` that preprocessor doesn't exist and it fails.</del>Update: This is not the problem as this situation is [accounted for](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/blob/master/markdown/extensions/extra.py#L61). There is no bug just user error as described below.

Interestingly, I noticed that you have both "extra" and "footnotes" listed as extensions. However, the "footnotes" extension is part of "extra". In other words, by loading "extra" you already get "footnotes" and don't need to load it a second time. The same can be said for "attr_list". This is what is causing the error. Trying to load the same extensions twice. In fact, the complete list of extensions which "extra" includes for you can be found [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/extra.html):

> - Abbreviations
> - Attribute Lists
> - Definition Lists
> - Fenced Code Blocks
> - Footnotes
> - Tables
> - Smart Strong

The only thing you loose by loading each of those extensions individually rather than all together as part of "extra" is less typing and the "markdown=1" feature (which allows Markdown to be parsed inside raw HTML blocks). Interestingly, if you are using `safe_mode`, then the "markdown=1" feature of "extra" is of no use to you. Therefore, rather than load "extra" you could simply load each of the individual extensions listed above and then `safe_mode` would still work.

That said, `safe_mode` is being [deprecated](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/release-2.6.html#safe_mode-deprecated) and will no longer be available in the next release of Python-Markdown. As explained in the the release notes, rather than using `safe_mode` you should be passing untrusted content through an HTML sanitizer (like [Bleach](http://bleach.readthedocs.org/)) after it is converted to HTML by markdown:

```
import bleach
html = bleach.clean(markdown.markdown(text), **MARKDOWN_KWARGS)
```

If you do that, then you can still get some security when parsing markdown from an untrusted source, you won't encounter the above mentioned bug, and your code will continue to work in future releases of Python-Markdown.